# Apache Ignite: How to move WAL to a different location?

Tags: java, caching, ignite, distributed

For a decent amount of time, I had placed the WAL and WAL archive at its default location.
But now I want to keep it away from the location where I store the data.

When I changed the WAL and WAL archive location in the code, I started getting an error related to the WAL segment index and WAL pointer.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Both compressed and raw segment files are missing in archive [segmentIdx=1234]
```

What is the correct way to move the WAL location from one to another?
Having trouble finding relevant information to this.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you copy all WAL files from old place to new while the node was stopped?

Comment: I have not, That is a good idea. But, in my case, it would be a hassle. 

Also, I do not really care about the existing cache data, and I am okay with letting go of the existing data and resetting things.

Comment: If you don't care about it, just nuke the existing persistence files. They're in `$IGNITE_HOME/work` by default

Comment: That is one way of doing it sure. I believe another way of accomplishing the same would be to copy the data and WAL files as is to the new location

Comment: You can also do that, just make sure to copy marshaller dir, db, wal and wal archive.

Answer (score 1):

look at my example

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration" >
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration" >
                <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 6GB. -->
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{30L* 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{30L* 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!-- Increasing the buffer size to 2 GB. -->
                        <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="4294967296"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                            <property name="name" value="InmemoryRegion"/>
                            <property name="maxSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                            <property name="initialSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                            <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_LRU"/>
                            <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <!-- 2GB Wal Segment Size -->
                <property name="walHistorySize" value="40"/>
                <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{1048570 * 1024 }"/>
                <property name="pageSize" value="#{16 * 1024}"/>
                <property name="walMode" value="FSYNC"/>
                <property name="storagePath" value="/home/user/db"/>
                <property name="walArchivePath" value="/home/user/walarchive"/>
                <property name="walPath" value="/home/user/pathtowal"/>
                <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="false"/>
                <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="alwaysWriteFullPages" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

Comment: ilya, 

I appreciate the answer but I already have my setup in place.
What I am struggling with is moving my WAL location from my existing directory to a new one.

If you have done that before, please do share your experience.